# Function returning record with interface field

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

After asking [this question about interface fields in records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293664/interface-field-in-record) I assumed that the following would work (notice the assertion):

```
type
  TRec <T> = record
    Intf : IInterface;
  end;

  TTestClass = class
  public
    function ReturnRec : TRec <Integer>;
  end;

  // Implementation 
  function TTestClass.ReturnRec : TRec <Integer>;
  begin
    Assert (Result.Intf = nil);    // Interface field in record should be initialized!
    Result.Intf := TInterfacedObject.Create;
  end;
```

I tested this with the following code:

```
  for I := 1 to 1000 do
    Rec := Test.ReturnRec;
```

and the assertion fails!

Where's my mistake here? What assumption is wrong?

Comment: Does the assertion fail on the first or second run of the loop?

Comment: @Smasher FWIW, this is what I was thinking of when I wrote my incorrect answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102843/delphi-function-result-not-emptied-during-for-loop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Function

```
function ReturnRec: TRec<Integer>;
```

Is semantically equal to procedure

```
procedure ReturnRec(var Result: TRec<Integer>);
```

[I'm pretty sure that somebody from Embarcadero, probably Barry Kelly or Alan Bauer stated this somewhere but I can't find the reference at the moment.]

In the second case, the compiler assumes that the record will be initialized (if necessary) before it is passed to the ReturnRec and doesn't create any initialization code for rec inside ReturnRec. I'm assuming that the same code path inside compiler is taken for the first example and that's why the Result is not initialized.

Anyway, the solution is simple:

```
function TTestClass.ReturnRec : TRec <Integer>;
begin
  Result.Intf := TInterfacedObject.Create;
end;
```

Just assume that compiler knows what it's doing and assign the interface and everything will work just fine.

EDIT

The problem you have occurs from the 'for' loop. Your code

```
for I := 1 to 1000 do
  Rec := Test.ReturnRec;
```

is compiled into something like this:

```
var
  result: TRec<Integer>;

Initialize(result);
for I := 1 to 1000 do begin
  Test.ReturnRec(result);
  rec := result;
end;
```

That is why you are reusing same record all over and that is why Result.Intf is uninitialized only the first time.

EDIT2

You can trick the compiler by moving t.ReturnRec call out from the loop into a separate method.

```
procedure GetRec(t: TTest; var rec: TRec);
begin
  rec := t.ReturnRec;
end;

for i := 1 to 1000 do
  GetRec(t, rec);
```

Now the hidden result variable lives in the GetRec procedure and is initialized every time GetRec is called.

Comment: Thanks gabr! I know the workaround but I dont like it, because I'm using this for a utility list record (like TList<T> but as record) and calling `Initialize` in all places is not very nice (kind of eliminates part of the advantage of having a record) :( especially since forgetting it can lead to some nasty bugs.

Comment: @Smasher You should always assign return values. Don't return unininitialzed values.

Comment: @David: okay, but until now I assumed that the return value **is** initialized, since the only relevant field is of an interface type. That would have been very nice for my usage scenario.

Comment: @Smasher This very issue that you have (re)discovered is precisely why you have no real option but to initialize even in your scenario.

Comment: @David agreed, but I would still consider this a bug.

Comment: @Smasher You could certainly view it as a bug. I bet you there are many QC reports already. No matter, my guess is that the compiler won't ever change and so you just have to accept it.

Comment: @Smasher I mis-remembered. The point I made about the `for` loop is only valid if you ignore the return value and the compiler has to make an implicit local variable.

Comment: Calling `Initialize` is *not* correct. It assumes that the value it receives is *invalid* and simply overwrites the record with valid values. Upon entry to the function, the value held in `Result.Intf` is a valid interface reference. **Calling `Initialize` on it leaks that reference.** You can call `Finialize` on it first, if you want, but I think it's more direct to simply assign `nil` to the fields that need it.

Comment: @gabr your solution **is** simple, but it does not work in my case. I'm using the interface solely to manage lifetime of an object kept in the record. If the interface is not nil, the object is not created and then all methods work on the instance created in the previous call. You understand?

Comment: I think I do. The problem here is that the same 'hidden' Result var is used for all calls to ReturnRec. You simply have to change the code - there is no simple workaround. I'll update the answer.