# List implementation with records

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, records

Follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518992/function-returning-record-with-interface-field): (note that this is not a duplicate, I'm asking for alternatives here).

Is there any way to make  the following work:

```
type
  List <T> = record
  private
    FList  : TList <T>;
    FGuard : IInterface,
    procedure CheckCreated;
  public
    procedure Add(const Value : T);
  end;

procedure List <T>.CheckCreated;
begin
if (FGuard = nil) then
  begin
  FList := TList <T>.Create;
  FGuard := TGuard.Create (FList);    // guard calls free on list in destructor
  end;
end;

procedure List <T>.Add (const Value : T);
begin
CheckCreated;
FList.Add (Value);
end;
```

Ideally I want to use it like this:

```
function ReturnHandles : List <THandle>;
begin
Result.Add (2);
Result.Add (3);
end;
```

As explained in the answers to the linked question, this does not work (which is really a pitty). It will not create a new list on each call.

Unfortunately this does not work either:

```
function ReturnHandles : List <THandle>;
begin
Initialize (Result);
Result.Add (2);
Result.Add (3);
end;
```

It leaks the guard interfaces and all the lists, because `Initialize` just overwrites the interface reference without decrementing the reference count.

Is there any way to make this work? Or would you suggest making this an interface instead of a record and just live with the construction line?

```
function ReturnHandles : List <THandle>;
begin
Result := List <T>.Create;
Result.Add (2);
Result.Add (3);   
end;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Rob explained in your last question that `Initialize` was an error in gabr's answer. So no you should not be using that.

Comment: That's what I wrote...the question is if there are any other ways to make this work or if is just not possible to create value types that contain objects

Comment: You're going against the rules in Delphi here.  You might get a certain distance down the "road" in doing things this way, but you'll find there are heavy costs to your RECORD type approach.

Comment: @WarrenP can you clarify what the "heavy costs" are in your opinion?

Comment: For example, do you intend to allow deep copies of these record-based lists?

Comment: @WarrenP Yes, `List.Copy`. Implicit copies behave the same way as references (internal list reference is copied), which is quite nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine if I understand you correctly:

```
function ReturnHandles : List <THandle>;
begin
  Finalize(Result);
  Result.Add (2);
  Result.Add (3);
end;
```

The `Finalize` call will ensure that all managed types are set to `nil` which I believe is your intent.

This question is very closely related to your previous question and I think that you could make use of `out` parameters to simplify the code. A function result is implicitly a `var` parameter, but if you used an explicit `out` parameter it will initialise the managed types as you desire.

```
procedure InitializeHandles(out Handles : List <THandle>);
begin
  Handles.Add (2);
  Handles.Add (3);
end;
```

Personally, since you are introducing an interface into the mix, I think I would be inclined to go all the way and use interfaces exclusively. Or use standard classes and accept the need for try/finally lifetime management.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that information! Not very intuitive though. I might go for the interface solution. Unfortunately I'll then loose the possiblity to use operator overloading :(

Comment: I have to say that I had never heard of this `Initialize` function until your question yesterday!

Comment: Thanks for the input! This is the first time that I find the language really limiting. Either I have to force all callers to remember to call `Finalize` when using it this way or I have to give up on operator overloading and generic methods within the list. Still some improvements possible to make the language more versatile I guess.

Comment: Have you tried using an `out` parameter rather than a function? An `out` has different semantics from a `var` parameter (which is what the function result is) and should do what you want.

Comment: Out parameter works, but eliminates part of the advantage of the whole idea: being able to write the more readable `Handles := GetHandles` instead of `GetHandles(Handles)`.

Comment: @Smasher Yes, I think there is no ideal solution here that achieves all of your goals